# Chart dispose and redraw

Tags: c#, charts

I have a few charts in a panel of a form, and the maximum and minimum values of the axis are programmatically set up based on user's data. I design to dispose the charts when I close the form. However,  when I reload the form and redraw the charts with different data, there are no updates on axis's max and min values. Don't know how to  handle the scenario. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code of how you initialize, add data to, and dispose of the chart?